# Opencart обновления корзины AJAX?

Tags: php, cms, opencart

Здравствуйте!

Нужно реализовать в корзине счетчик товаров с обновлением цены без перезагрузки (AJAX).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел стандартную функцию в `OpenCart` `cart.update(key, quanity) {$.ajax ...}`

Не могу понять, что является `key` ?? Как я понимаю это не `$product['cart_id']`.

Или может есть другая возможность в `Opencart` обновить корзину `ajax`?

Answer (score 1):

`key` - это `cart_id` в таблице `oc_cart`. В шаблоне это `$product['cart_id]`. Чтобы достать его со стороны JS не изменяя ничего на странице можно взять его у соответствующего поля ввода. Имя поля (аттрибут `name`) имеет вид `quantity[значение cart_id]`.

**Дополнено**

При более внимательном рассмотрении видно, что этот функционал разработчики поломали (по крайней мере в версии 2.1). Требуется переработать метод `edit` класса `ControllerCheckoutCart`

```
public function edit() {
    $this->load->language('checkout/cart');

    $json = array();

    // Update
    if (is_array($this->request->post['quantity']) 
        && !empty($this->request->post['quantity'])
    ) {
        foreach ($this->request->post['quantity'] as $key => $value) {
            $this->cart->update($key, $value);
        }

        unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
        unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
        unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
        unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
        unset($this->session->data['reward']);

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
    } else if (is_numeric($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
        $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), 
            $this->cart->countProducts()
                + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers'])
                    ? count($this->session->data['vouchers'])
                    : 0), 
            $this->currency->format($total)
        );
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но при ajax запросе cart.update(id). Выбивает ошибка (http://prntscr.com/cf7h02)

Comment: @Victor-AA Дополнил ответ, но не проверял